# How to move image follow Y with (X,Y) receive from touch event in Android?

Tags: android, animation

How to move image follow Y with (X,Y) receive from touch event in Android?
This my event touch for call method RocketFly, mrthod RocketFly send X, Y for method run() below:

```
private void eventTouchScreen() {
        viewMyLayout.setOnTouchListener(new ConstraintLayout.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++)
                {
                    float x = event.getX(i);
                    float y = event.getY(i);
                    int id = event.getPointerId(i);
                    int action = event.getActionMasked();
                    int actionIndex = event.getActionIndex();

                    String actionName;
                    switch (action) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            actionName = "UP";
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            actionName = "DOWN";
                            break;
                        default:
                            actionName = "";
                    }
                    String touchName = "Action: " + actionName + " Index: " + actionIndex + " ID: " + id + " X: " + x + " Y: " + y;
                    if (actionName.equals("UP")) {
                        //txtTouch.setText(touchName);
                        System.out.println(touchName);
                        RocketFly(x, y);
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

when start run() and it draw below, it image has show but it don't move follow y--, how image move when y change?

```
public void run(ImageView img, Bitmap bitmap) {
        while (this.y > 0)
        {
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
            //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, paint);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            this.y--;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

every added `View` have `LayoutParams`

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = img.getLayoutParams();
```

depending of parent of `img`, but in most cases you can cast it to

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) params;
```

an this class may setup margins of `View` - use [setMargins](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams#setMargins(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method to add or subtract proper values

note that if parent of your `img` is fixed, e.g. `img` is declared in some XML inside `LinearLayout` then you can cast `params` straight to `LinearLayoyt.LayoutParams`, which gives you more possibilities of manipulating position, size, visibility etc.

Comment: but params is not setImageBitmap(), I can't draw img

Comment: after setting image to `ImageView` use `LayoutParams` to move this `ImageView` inside its parent. calculate proper margins after setting image

Comment: I'm sorry, I not foung position or location v.v I am doing game, image is start after touch on A(x, y) and end B(x, y + 100), I try to it